How to prove $\forall a,b \in \mathbb Z,(a\equiv _n\circ\equiv_m b)$?
I am trying to analyze the following statement, which I believe is true, but I would appreciate guidance on proving it (or counterexamples if it is false):
$$
\forall n, m \in \mathbb{N}^{\geq 2}, n \neq m \implies \forall a, b \in \mathbb{Z}, (a \equiv_n \circ \equiv_m b)
$$
Here, $ \equiv_n \circ \equiv_m $ is a relation on $ \mathbb{Z} $, defined as:
$$
\equiv_n \circ \equiv_m = \{(a, b) \in \mathbb{Z}^2 \mid \exists c \in \mathbb{Z}, a \equiv_n c \text{ and } c \equiv_m b \}.
$$
Where $ \equiv_n $ represents equivalence modulo $ n $, given by:
$$
\equiv_n = \{(a, b) \in \mathbb{Z}^2 \mid \exists k \in \mathbb{Z}, a = kn + b\}.
$$
My question is as follows:

Is the composition $ \equiv_n \circ \equiv_m $ well-defined for all $ n \neq m $?
If so, how can this be proven? If not, could you provide a counterexample or explain why?

Any help in clarifying or proving this would be greatly appreciated!

That's not true, for example you can take $n = 2$, $m = 4$, $a = 0$ and $b = 1$.

You should look up the Chinese Remainder Theorem

$\equiv_n \circ \equiv_m$ is literally just $\equiv_{\text{gcd}(m, n)}$.

See the CRT Solvability Criterion in the linked dupe. $\ \ $

So it is true if $\gcd(n,m)=1$ @Adayah

Yeah. $\phantom{}$
